# Getting an error in sql, when executing code below.How to declare a table type in plsql. Am a beginner . Please suggest

Tags: sql, plsql

```
 create or replace procedure BAS_NUM_UPD  is

 cursor cur is

 select distinct o.oi_b,mpr.pa_ke_i,ltrim(substr(convert_171_to_711(cp.p_t_num),1,7),'0') bs_nbr

    from t_obj o, mat_pa_rel mp, cor_pa cp
    where o.ob_t = 'something'
    and o.oi_b = mp.oi_b
    and mp.pa_ke_i = cp.pa_ke_i;

 l_ba_num_at_i  number(10) := get_attribute_id('Ba  timber');

 flag1 VARCHAR2(10);

 type t1 is table of varchar2(10);
 par_k t1;

 BEGIN
     for x in cur loop
 BEGIN      

   select pa_ke_i into par_k from mat_pa_rel where oi_b=x.oi_b ;

  if par_k.count=null  then  

  insert into cs_val (oi_b, at_i, value, flag, ) values (x.oi_b, l_ba_num_at_i, null, 1);

  end if;

  select flag into flag1 from cs_val where at_i = l_ba_num_at_i  and oi_b = x.oi_b
    and value = x.bs_nbr;

  EXCEPTION 

    when NO_DATA_FOUND THEN

      insert into cs_val (oi_b, at_i, value, flag, )
          values (x.oi_b, l_ba_num_at_i, x.bs_nbr, 1);

    flag1 :='Nothing';

    when OTHERS 
then
       raise_application_error(-20011,'Unknown Exception in PROCEDURE');
END;

end loop;
end BAS_NUM_UPD;
```

error:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Comment: Honestly, your design looks a bit odd. Couldn't this lead to 2 inserts into cs_val? If count = 0 and a no-data-found exception then you will end up with 2 records in cs_val for the same oi_b and at_i. This could in turn trigger another error. Maybe you should brush up on plsql basics too: if you want to count records and the first thing you think of is loading records into a self-declared type, and not a count(*), then you are not up to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get it running if you do a bulk collect

```
select pa_ke_i bulk collect into par_k from mat_pa_rel where oi_b=x.oi_b ;
```

Then I think the if is not right. I think you need to do

```
if par_k.count = 0 then
```

But to be honest you might just make a count

```
select count(*) into l_cnt from mat_pa_rel where oi_b=x.oi_b;

If l_cnt = 0 then ...
```

Of course l_cnt has to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `type t1` in the schema and not in the pl/sql block.

Comment: I did something like this in my sql plus create or replace type t1 is table of varchar2(10); and got  the error as       ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PLS-00565: T1 must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)     can you please tell me how to define a table type in schema

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T1" 
as table of varchar2(10);

Comment: BUT ITS STILL GIVING THE SAME ERROR. i AM DOING IT IN SQL PLUS.

Comment: Strange... I've copied/pasted in SQL Developer and worked. I'll try sql plus now.

Comment: yes andrea i got it in plsql . but am getting an error at  :  select pa_ke_i into par_k from mat_pa_rel where oi_b=x.oi_b ;   saying that  Error(22,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored and Error(22,11): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER.

Comment: I need your suggestion . i will describe here what am trying to do. The table mat_pa_rel will return n number of pa_ke_i for each oi_b. I am checking if for any oi_b there are no values of pa_ke_i related in  mat_pa_rel and then insert null in 'VALUE' COLUMN. Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks a lot.My way is not working out for me , donno why. Please help .